# change protocol in electron main.js

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, electron, protocols

When trying to use firebase UI for login in electron app, I come across this issue:

> This operation is not supported in the environment this application is
>   running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or
>   chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled

But I cannot change the protocol in loadURL in main.js, do you have any idea how can I make the firebase UI think that the protocol is http?

```
mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({ pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'login.html'), protocol: 'file:', slashes: true }))
```

Comment: What operation are you trying to use? OAuth sign in via popup/redirect? If so, for non-http/https environments or when web storage is not supported, you can sign in the user with the OAuth provider using a third party library of via a browser, get the provider OAuth access token and then use `signInWithCredential` to sign in to Firebase with that provider.

Comment: I am using the firebase UI which handles everything. It just adds a sign in ui in your app and handles every single thing so I didn't write any popup or redirect. How can I sign in the user using third party library?

Comment: Hmm, I think FirebaseUI may not be compatible for your case. It is meant to work for traditional browser apps. It calls signInWithRedirect to sign in with OAuth providers. Are you building a desktop app?

Comment: yes I am building a desktop app. But it is supposed to work the same way as web apps. I still could not find a fix for this issue. I somehow need to make electron show the protocol as http: